# Bootstrap js doesn't load sometimes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm getting complaints from users on multiple browsers and devices that Bootstrap JS isn't loading on some website pages. Pages always differ and it's typically only one webpage per session, while other pages render normally.

**What I've Tried:**
I am using the MaxCDN for Bootstrap 3 for JS and CSS. 
JQuery is loaded first. 
No errors in Console Log

Here are the scripts I'm using:

```
<!-- jQuery Version - 1.12.3 -->
<script src="../../assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is what it looks like on Chrome: 
[Bootstrap JS not rendering in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jq4m.png)

Same user also visited other website pages that rendered normally.

Comment: Are you using cloudflare on your website, it could be one of the causes if you are let me tell you what to do.

Comment: Will it load on a page refresh? Or is this specific page always doing it for the duration of the session? Are you able to reproduce the issue? If so, look in the dev tool under the network tab and see what's breaking.

Comment: adding to what @amflare said your link is not working. Bootstrap JS not rendering in Chrome

Comment: try to add these link at end of the page

Comment: @amflare , I am only finding these issues by watching user recordings (with Hotjar) and have not been able to reproduce the issue myself. None of the users in the recordings attempted to refresh. But they did visit other pages which rendered fine.

Comment: Well, from your code, there is no discernible reason for it to break. I recommend getting more information from your users if you can.